# Learn the evaluation matrix for hire a job candidate

Tags: neural-network, data-science-model

Let us assume that we have a certain number of features that are weighted with some parameters . The features could be the different skills that belongs to a job candidate  applying for a job vacancies .  The decision to give a job to the single candidate is based on a weighted sum of a different features .So we have a neural network model on which we have to learn the matrix that associate the  variable x = features  that a candidate has to y = ( hire/not hire)
I was wondering what is the name in literature of this problem and where i can find suggestion to solve it.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

its a simple DNN problem when you have x features and y labels you can have some data for NN training and then NN can be used to classify other candidates. I have a program already made for this plz comment if you need one .

Comment: You are completely right but more than the algorithm I was wondering if exists a dataset for the training of the algorithm. I tried to google it but I think it is difficult to find a company dataset that has been modelled like a DNN problem like this.  This is main reason that pushed me to ask how others tackled the same problem.

Comment: Hi anton u r also right about the dataset as its kind of proprietary to companies but may be its an opportunity to create one. And than we can open source it as well. I know how to extract features from text and if you have enough CVs than we can go for this.

Comment: Interesting proposal , my idea is that we need two abstractions to tackle the problem . The first is the features extraction from resume in a smart way  and the second is the creation of the complex features from the simple feature extracted from the resume. Then we can go unsupervised I Suppose.

Comment: the second complex feature creation from simple features is also possible and there are quite a number of research paper on it. So how should we go about it now

Comment: Ok then after the creation of a vector containing N predictors like ( age, salary requested , number of job transition in the past 5 years etc extracted  from the resume ) we have N weights that measure the importance of the predictors for the different companies . The final score is one row of the matrix . Is this feasible in your opinion to populate a matrix like this ?